# Google Spreadsheet script to Return table of subtotals

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my function to import a range (6 columns ; and lots of rows) from active spreadsheet and return subtotal grouped by the 5th column.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rows = sheet.getRange("A3:F");
var values = rows.getValues(); 
var expense = new Array();
var expensehead = new Array();
for (var i = 0, e = 0; i <= rows.getNumRows()-1; i++) {

    if (values[i][0] instanceof Date & values[i][2] == "Expense") {  // As long as col0 is a date and col2 == "Expense"
        if (expense.hasOwnProperty(values[i][4])) {
        // if the index "Expense Category" (col4) already exists in the array, add the amount (col 5) to the existing value
        // Add amount (col 5) array expense where index is "Expense Category" (col4)
        // For example Expense['Food'] = Expense['Food']  + 100;  Emulating it like an associative array here
        expense[values[i][4]]= expense[values[i][4]] + values[i][5]; 
      }
      else {
        // The index "Expense Category" (col4) does already exists in the array, assign the amount (col 5) to the new index
        // Add amount (col 5) array expense where index is "Expense Category" (col4)
        // For example Expense['Food'] = 100;  I have spet on food for the first time, hence it does not exist in the array already. Emulating it like an associative array here
        expense[values[i][4]]= values[i][5]; 

        //Since Javascript or Google script does not support iteration in an associative array, 
        //I am adding all indexes to another array expensehead so i will be able to pull out the info later.
        expensehead.push(values[i][4])
      } 
    }
  }
```

My Problem:

I know that using array is a bad idea here. I want to use something like a 2D key value pair or an associative array (or some spreadsheet equivalent object)

Can someone point me to an Google spreadsheet object that i can use and also state methods by which  can return the 2 columns "Expense category' and SUM(amount) subtotal.

PS1: I dont want to use pivot table report as i will be introducing additional date based filters that pivot table does not support. (see below)
PS2: I am currently using spreadsheet's built-in function "query" (see below) but i dont like it because it cannot give me Grand Total of sub totals like Pivots do.
=query(A2:F;"SELECT SUM(F), D where C like 'Expense' AND A >= date '"& mkdate(I1) &"' AND A <= date '"& mkdate(L1) &"' group by D Order by SUM(F) Label SUM(F) 'Amount', D 'Expense Category' ")
PS3: I considered using a Sql query like above and running a pivot table on it to generate Subtotals, but i feel like a looser. Besides i have about 1000 rows in the data which makes it super slow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I built a function that may help.  I have a set of helper functions that I use in a lot of my spreadsheets.  But here it is.

Usage:

`var DistNTax = SpreadsheetApp
                .openById(SheetID)
                .getSheetByName('Sheet1')
                .getRange('N2:S')
                .getValues();`

`var DistNTax  = SumColArray_(DistNTax);`

```
for (var d = 0,LOCNUML=LocNum.length; d < LOCNUML; d++)                                    //Builds 2d Looping-Array to allow choosing of columns at a future point
          {
            SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Database').getRange(CurrentEmpty + d,1).setValue(FuncName);    //getRange(Row,Col,RowAdd,ColAdd)
            SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Database').getRange(CurrentEmpty + d,2).setValue(TimeFrame);   //getRange(Row,Col,RowAdd,ColAdd)
            SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Database').getRange(CurrentEmpty + d,5).setValue(DistNTax[d]);   //getRange(Row,Col,RowAdd,ColAdd)
          }
```

­

```
//~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`
//--//Dependent on cleanArray_()
// Array Column Sum Agent
function SumColArray_(sumagent)
{
    var newArray = new Array();
    for(var i = 0, sL = sumagent.length; i<sL; i++)
    {
       var totalsum = 0
       var CleanForSum = cleanArray_(sumagent[i]);
       for(var d = 0, CFSL = CleanForSum.length; d<CFSL; d++)
       {  
        totalsum += CleanForSum[d];
       }
      newArray.push(Math.round(totalsum));
    }
    return newArray;
}
//~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`



//~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`
//--//Dependent on isEmpty_()
// Blank Array Extractor/Rebuilder
function cleanArray_(actual)
{
    var newArray = new Array();
    for(var i = 0, aL = actual.length; i<aL; i++)
    {
        if (isEmpty_(actual[i]) == false)
        {
            newArray.push(actual[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
//~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`



//~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`
// Empty String Check
function isEmpty_(string) 
{

    if(!string)             return true;         
    if(string == '')        return true;
    if(string === false)    return true; 
    if(string === null)     return true; 
    if(string == undefined) return true;
    string = string+' '; // check for a bunch of whitespace
    if('' == (string.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''))) return true;       
    return false;        
}
//~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`~,~`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use objects / associative arrays instead of a javascript array, take a look at the [ObjService Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/gs-objects). You could then do something like this:

```
...
var expense = ObjLib.rangeToObjects(values);

for (var i in expense) {
  if (expense[i].expenseCategory != null) {
    ...
  }
}
```